# Make some text and image align with correct size

Tags: html, css

I'm trying create some kind of sections where you have some text on one side of the page and an image on the other side of the page. But I'm having trouble to make it have a good size, currently my image is too big so it looks kinda ugly.
Does it depend on my image? Because I can reduce the height of the image but then the quality turns bad (See this for [what I'm trying to achieve](https://res.cloudinary.com/hl8zoliad/raw/upload/npm/react-native-text-input-layout.png)).

HTML

```
<div className='parcours_presentation'>
            <div className='col parcours_presentation-left'>
            <h1>PARCOURS STARTER</h1>
            <h3>Bilan sur 2 mois</h3>
            <p>
                this is some text
            </p>
            </div>
            <div className='col parcours_presentation-right'>
                <img src={radioImg} alt='img' />
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.parcours_presentation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5%;
}
.parcours, p, h1, h3 {
    color: black;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
}

.col{
    width: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try this approach. Let me know

```css
.parcours_presentation{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    text-align:center;
    align-items: center;
    margin: 5%;
    background: rgb(105,27,173);
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(105,27,173,1) 37%, rgba(144,35,197,1) 69%, rgba(144,35,197,1) 93%);
}

.parcours, p, h1, h3 {
    color: black;
}

img{
    max-width: 100%;
    border-radius:20px;
    height:300px;
    width:300px;
    object-fit:cover;
}  



.parcours_presentation-right {
    display:grid
    justify-content:center;
    padding:10px;
    
}
```

```html
<div class="parcours_presentation">
  <div >
  
     <h1> PARCOURS STARTER</h1>
     
     <hr>
        <h3>Bilan sur 2 mois</h3>
            <p> this is some text </p>
  </div>
            
   <div class="parcours_presentation-right">
      <img src="https://www.gardenia.net/storage/app/public/plant_family/detail/83649435_mOptimized.jpg"  style="float:left"/>

   </div>
        
</div>
```

Comment: Yes it's not that bad, do you know how I can make the image looks a bit bigger?

Comment: all you need to do is adjust the width and height of the img. i made it 300px. Let me know if this all looks good on you.

Comment: you're welcome please accept the answer by clicking the check on the left side so your issue is already resolved from the others :) Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

I don't think I can do anything with the information you have given me, right now. If you could post something to give me some more info, I would be glad to help you!

Comment: like what information would you need?

Answer (score 0):

How about `height: inherit;`

```css
.parcours_presentation {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
}

.parcours_presentation .col.parcours_presentation-right {
    height: inherit;
    padding: 30px;
}

.parcours_presentation .col.parcours_presentation-right img {
    object-fit: cover;
    object-position: center;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: nah, it makes the image take the whole page.